# Static column header in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to make a static column header in WPF datagrid, so the user will see the column headers/names, when scrolling down if table is too long.

However, I am really new to this WPF/C# thing, and I am no sure how to do it, and if it will be in cs part, or xaml part. I have searched many possible solutions, but most of them were for asp.net [link](http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=144&Desc=Fixed-Header-GridView) or I found even nice HTML/CSS solution to this, or even some plugins to do so.

However, my question remains - how to make datagrid column header static, and should I do it in cs part or xaml part?

Thanks

Edit: as I am just fixing larger part of code, it would be too difficult to post it all. However, I read those problems with scrolviewer, and I found there this part of code, which might have caused it:

```
var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer()
    {
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
    };

    scrollViewer.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.MouseWheelHandler), true);
    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;
```

So - could this caused it, and do you have advice how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code, afaik this is the standard functionality of the WPF Datagrid

Comment: Post your current code and XAML.

Comment: Here is the part of which in my opinion might have caused - only place where scroll viewer is mentioned